# PHP form - Stay on same page after submitting

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm trying to submit a form, and stay on the same page after submiting.

My website is using a form to submit data. I have a main HTML script (e.g. `website.html`) with my form, and a PHP script (e.g. `query_data.php`).

Here's a part of my html script :

```
<form action="query_data.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="geo" id="geo" class="selectors myDropdown">
        <option value="base">Location</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

And here's my php script :

```
<?php
$db = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=location user=postgres password=xxxxxxxx");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $sql = "SELECT id, title, geo, lat, lng, ST_AsGeoJSON((ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lat, lng), 4326)), 4) as geom
    FROM locations WHERE geo LIKE $1";
    $result = pg_prepare($db, "query", $sql);
    $query = pg_execute($db, "query", array("%".$_POST['geo']."%"));

    $features = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < pg_numrows($query); $i++) {
        $row = pg_fetch_assoc($query,$i);
        $geometry = $row['geom'] = json_decode($row['geom']);
        unset($row['geom']);
        // Nous retirons les résultats redondants
        unset($row[0]);
        unset($row[1]);
        unset($row[2]);
        unset($row[3]);
        unset($row[4]);
        // Nous reconstituons notre 'feature' sur le modèle GeoJSON
        $feature = ['type' => 'Feature', 'geometry' => $geometry, 'properties' => $row];
        array_push($features, $feature);
    };

    $featureCollection = ["type" => "FeatureCollection", "features" => $features];
    foreach($features as $item) { //foreach element in $arr
        $id = strval($item['properties']["id"]);
        $title = str_replace("'", " ", (strval($item['properties']["title"])));
        $geo = pg_escape_string(strval($item['properties']["geo"]));
        $lat = $item['properties']["lat"];
        $lng = $item['properties']["lng"];
        $query = "INSERT INTO query_data VALUES ('$id', '$title', '$geo', '$lat', '$lng')";
        $result = pg_query($query);
    }
    pg_close($db);  
}
header('Location: index.html');
exit;
?>
```

Using the `header('Location: index.html');` partly solved my problem, but it's not an ideal solution because it automatically refreshes my website which reset all values. Is there a way to submit my form without leaving the page ?

Comment: Use AJAX instead of normal form submission.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Are you struggling with the PHP part, the JS part, or the HTML part?